# Name or closed form for given description of a function

Tags: functions

I am looking for the name or nice explicit formula for the following function:

I give you a positive integer N, and the function I want from you, say, f(X), subtracts X from N until the result is less than X, but not zero or negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ceiling function, we can write it as
$$
f(X)=N-\left\lceil\frac{N}{X}-1\right\rceil X
$$
Note that if $N$ is divisible by $X$, then $f(X)=X$. It's either that, or remove the ${}-1$ and switch to the floor function, which would make $f(X)=0$ in those cases.

If you're doing this in a programming language, then using the `%` operator is exactly what you're looking for, and you can express `f(X)` as `(N-1)%X+1`.

Comment: I assume simply iterating this produces the function I ask for. Correct? It works with a few numbers I've checked.

Comment: @JohhnyApple What do you mean by "iterating"?

Comment: When $N=7$ and $x=\pi $ we have $ f(x) =7-2\pi .$  But your formula gives $ 7-$Floor $(6/\pi)\cdot \pi=7-\pi.$

Comment: @user254665 It is now fixed and should work for any real number $X$.

Comment: @Arthur. I think your formula is better than mine.

Comment: @user254665 Note that we actually have more or less the same formula, since the difference between the ceiling function and the floor function is exactly $1-g(x)$. I could've put my $-1$ outside the ceiling function, which would've made the similarity clearer, but I thought it was prettier to leave it inside, since then I won't need the extra parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=\chi_{\mathbb N}$ be the characteristic function of the positive integers. That is, $g(x)=1$ if $x$ is a positive integer, otherwise $g(x)=0.$ Then $$f(x)=N-x(\;Floor(N/x)-g(N/x)\;).$$

For if $N/x\in \mathbb N$ then $Floor (N/x)=N/x$ and $g(N/x)=1,$ and the formula gives $f(x)=N-x(N/x-1)=x.$

And if $N/x\not \in \mathbb N$ then $g(N/x)=0 ,$ and the formula gives  $f(x)=N-x(\; Floor(N/x)), $ which is positive, while $N-x(1+Floor (N/x))$ is negative.